# Saving result of applescript execution to text file

Tags: applescript

In my script, I get the UI element properties of an application and it is saved in the form of a list in a variable. I want to save this variable into a text file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
-- Example elements
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set uiElements to (get UI elements)
end tell


set uiTextList to {}
repeat with uiE in uiElements
    try
        set uiText to uiE as text
        set end of uiTextList to uiText
    on error errMsg
        set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"Can’t make ", " into type text."}}
        set end of uiTextList to text item 2 of errMsg
        set text item delimiters to TID
    end try
end repeat

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (uiTextList as text) & " > " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
set the textFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "filename.txt"
open for access file the textFile with write permission
write ("Whatever you want to write" & return) to file the textFile starting at eof
close access file the textFile
```

Comment: This will not work unless each ui element's class is text. A reference such as menu bar 1 of application process "Finder" of application "System Events" will return an error.